# Selecionar o primeiro resultado de cada conversa

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlfiddle

Como eu posso selecionar a primeira linha de cada conversa de um usuário específico onde o `to_id = 1`.

O grande problema é quando a primeira mensagem trocada da conversa não tem o `top_id = 1` e acaba listando a próxima mensagem da conversa que possui o `from_id = 1`, quando não deveria.

Aqui está o link para o SQLFIDDLE:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a772b/4

No SQLFIDDLE está listando o `Test 1` e o `Test 4` quando deveria estar listando apenas o `Test 1`, por que a conversa `Test 4` começa no `Test 3` onde não tem o `to_id = 1`.

SQL

```
SELECT t1.*, m2.message, m2.from_id FROM
    (SELECT to_id,message, MIN(created_at) AS created_at FROM messages m
    WHERE to_id = 1
    GROUP BY to_id,message) AS t1
INNER JOIN messages m2 ON t1.created_at = m2.created_at
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
SELECT m1.to_id, m1.message, m1.created_at, m1.from_id
FROM messages m1
WHERE m1.to_id = 1
AND m1.created_at <= IFNULL(
                      (SELECT m2.created_at
                      FROM messages m2
                      WHERE (m2.from_id = m1.to_id AND m2.to_id = m1.from_id)
                      OR (m2.from_id = m1.from_id AND m2.to_id = m1.to_id)
                      LIMIT 1)
                    , NOW())
GROUP BY m1.to_id, m1.created_at
```

Comment: Cara, quando um usuario envia duas mensagens antes do outro usuario enviar pelo menos uma, acaba nao listando. Tens alguma ideia pra arrumar isso?

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c8e09/2 Nesse exemplo deveria continuar listando o "test 1" e "test 3", mas lista somente o "test 1"

Comment: Vi a tua edição e tá retornando o test 3 certinho, mas o problema é que tá retornando o test 4 também.

Comment: Adicionei a clausula IFNULL para quando não existe uma resposta e o OR depois do WHERE pra filtrar quando o usuário envia duas ou mais mensagens seguidas.

Comment: Show! Valeu mesmo!

Answer (score 1):

Fiz da forma que achei correta, testei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente.

```
SELECT 
  t1.* 
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM messages) t1 
  INNER JOIN messages t2 
    ON (t2.id = t1.from_id AND t2.from_id = t1.id)
WHERE t1.to_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A query está bem planejada, o problema está na organização dela.

Sua query atual (SQLFiddle) está assim

```
SELECT t1.*, m2.message, m2.from_id FROM
    (SELECT to_id,message, MIN(created_at) AS created_at FROM messages m
    WHERE to_id = 1
    GROUP BY to_id,message) AS t1
INNER JOIN messages m2 ON t1.created_at = m2.created_at
```

Você está passando tanto o `id` quanto `message` como referência para o `GROUP BY` o que ironicamente não tem lógica.

Para funcionar basta remover `message` do `GROUP BY`, deixando sua query assim

```
SELECT t1.*, m2.message, m2.from_id FROM
    (SELECT to_id,message, MIN(created_at) AS created_at FROM messages m
    WHERE to_id = 1
    GROUP BY to_id) AS t1
INNER JOIN messages m2 ON t1.created_at = m2.created_at
```

SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a772b/10

Comment: Não pode ser desse jeito, por que quando a conversa entre o usuário 1 e 3 começa com o "to_id = 1" não lista ele. Fiz uma pequena alteração nos dados da tabela pra tu ter uma ideia: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/154fa9/7

Comment: Nesse caso sim deveria listar o "Test 1" e "Test 3".

Comment: Ficou bem confuso! Na thread você diz que deveria listar apenas o Test 1, no caso a query deve puxar as 2 conversar, tanto Test 1 e Teste 3? Mesmo que seja assim não tem lógica usar group by em ambos. Vou dar uma olhada nessa outra query

Comment: Falei que naquele exemplo deveria listar apenas o test 1

Comment: A ideia geral é listar a primeira mensagem trocada entre o usuário 1 com os demais, onde essa primeira mensagem tenha o to_id = 1

Comment: O problema é que quando alguém começa mandando uma mensagem pro usuário 1, e depois ele responde, não pode listar essa conversa por que ela não começou com o usuário 1 recebendo mensagem. Esse é o exemplo que eu mandei no SQLFIDDLE agora por último.

Comment: Se bem entendi, o usuário X envia uma mensagem pro usuário Y, e o usuário X responde, essa conversa não pode ser exibida, mas se o usuário X não responde, ela deve ser listada, isso para todos os usuários?

Comment: A ideia é listar a primeira mensagem de cada conversa que o usuário logado não iniciou. Não importa se ele respondeu ou não

Comment: No caso do teu exemplo, se o usuário X está logado, não deveria listar a primeira mensagem que ele mandou pro usuário Y. Porém se o usuário Y está logado, deveria listar, pois ele recebeu a mensagem primeiro.